# How to assign a slice to a hashmap

Tags: go, hashmap

I am trying to make a hash map containing keys like "cow", "bird", etc. and to each key, I want to assign a slice.

I am unable to understand how I should go about this, and even if I created it how to append to such slice.

Comment: Go does not have hash maps.  I assume you just mean a map?  Why not `map[string][]string`?

Comment: sorry i meant maps. Also even if I do that I am not able to access the value as a string slice. Go considers it as a string

Comment: "Go considers it as a string" -- Go considers _what_ a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
    animalMap := make(map[string][]string, 0)

    animalMap["cow"] = []string{"Alice", "Bob"}
    animalMap["bird"] = []string{"Tweety", "Sam"}

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", animalMap)

    // Appending value to existing slice for "cow"
    animalMap["cow"] = append(animalMap["cow"], "Chris")

    // Appending value to existing slice for "bird"
    animalMap["bird"] = append(animalMap["bird"], "Tom")

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", animalMap)
```

Here's the live example: https://play.golang.org/p/YXS-IlWUPfi

Comment: Yes very much the same thing, but the problem comes up while appending values. That is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Ahh in that case, I modified my answer to the following

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    slice2 := []string{"d", "e", "f"}
    mp := make(map[string]*[]string, 0) // Initialize map
    mp["slice1"] = &slice1
    mp["slice2"] = &slice2
    for k, v := range mp {
        // k is key, v is value
        fmt.Println(k, *v)
    }
}
```